# Make EVERY Element proportional positioned when resizing window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

(I use HTML, CSS, Bootstrap 3.3.7 with Gridsystem, I'm new to JS/jQuery)

Hey guys,

I'm building a SPA (single page application) that has multiple  elements, each `100vh`, so it should look like 4 different "slides".

**My problem:**

I don't want the DIVs, images, headings and paragraphs to be responsive in terms of stacking elements under and over depending on the window size.

The elements should move pretty much proportionally however I size the browser window. Like if you make a picture bigger and smaller. Everything should shrink together with a pretty much **proportional scaling** if I make the window smaller.

I am sure there is the knowledge out there but please help me I'm too stupid I googled half an hour and didn't find anything.

Do you know the attributes and styles I need to apply to my elements to get rid of the ugly over-stacking of elements? To give things a proportional scaling.

A thousand thanks!

Comment: The explanation you gave is a little unclear and without pictures or code that shows what you're tried or what you're trying to achieve it's hard to understand what you want. Also: proportional to what? What is the standard?

But what comes to mind is the * selector, which is a universal selector that selects *every* element on the page. Example: `* { width: 90% }`

Comment: You can use `flexbox` to achieve this

Comment: `Like if you make a picture bigger and smaller.` - do you mean resizing the window?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100%;

}
.item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
<span class='item'>1</span>
<span class='item'>2</span>
<span class='item'>3</span>
<span class='item'>4</span>
</div>
```

You can use this snippet as reference. Let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Flex` for this requirement.

> You can easily constrain blocks from stacking by simply using `col-xs-*`

```css
.block {
  height: 100vh;
  background: gray;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```